# Python matching two lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [[0, 5], [5, 115], [115, 219], [219, 262], [262, 328], [328, 408], [408, 424], [424, 531], [531, 562], [562, 620], [620, 676], [676, 781], [781, 805], [805, 808], [808, 919], [919, 1009], [1009, 1112], [1112, 1183], [1183, 1241], [1241, 1254], [1254, 1283], [1283, 1323], [1323, 1346], [1346, 1362], [1362, 1383], [1383, 1472], [1472, 1548], [1548, 1559], [1559, 1578], [1578, 1600], [1600, 1642], [1642, 1693], [1693, 1700], [1700, 1763], [1763, 1843], [1843, 1861], [1861, 1966], [1966, 1982], [1982, 2135], [2135, 2150], [2150, 2159], [2159, 2197], [2197, 2233], [2233, 2253], [2253, 2301], [2301, 2358], [2358, 2377], [2377, 2394], [2394, 2419], [2419, 2438], [2438, 2453], [2453, 2486], [2486, 2506], [2506, 2515], [2515, 2528], [2528, 2554], [2554, 2559], [2559, 2577], [2577, 2637], [2637, 2694], [2694, 2716], [2716, 2737], [2737, 2764], [2764, 2777], [2777, 2779], [2779, 2779]]
```

and

```
list2 = [[0, 145, 0], [145, 169, 1], [169, 1693, 3], [1693, 1708, 1], [1708, 2729, 3], [2729, 2779, 0]]
```

I want to match them, as if list1[1] is equal or inbetween list2[1] it takes the third value in the brackets and adds them to list in list1 (sorry my english is poor!) If it does not fit to one explicitly, add the value 2. The result should look like that:

```
list1 = [[0, 5, 0], [5, 115, 0], [115, 219, 2], [219, 262, 3], [262, 328, 3], [328, 408, 3], [408, 424, 3], [424, 531, 3], [531, 562, 3], [562, 620, 3], [620, 676, 3], [676, 781, 3], [781, 805, 3], [805, 808, 3], [808, 919, 3], [919, 1009, 3], [1009, 1112, 3], [1112, 1183, 3], [1183, 1241, 3], [1241, 1254, 3], [1254, 1283, 3], [1283, 1323, 3], [1323, 1346, 3], [1346, 1362, 3], [1362, 1383, 3], [1383, 1472, 3], [1472, 1548, 3], [1548, 1559, 3], [1559, 1578, 3], [1578, 1600, 3], [1600, 1642, 3], [1642, 1693, 3], [1693, 1700, 1], [1700, 1763, 2], [1763, 1843, 3], [1843, 1861, 3], [1861, 1966, 3], [1966, 1982, 3], [1982, 2135, 3], [2135, 2150, 3], [2150, 2159, 3], [2159, 2197, 3], [2197, 2233, 3], [2233, 2253, 3], [2253, 2301, 3], [2301, 2358, 3], [2358, 2377, 3], [2377, 2394, 3], [2394, 2419, 3], [2419, 2438, 3], [2438, 2453, 3], [2453, 2486, 3], [2486, 2506, 3], [2506, 2515, 3], [2515, 2528, 3], [2528, 2554, 3], [2554, 2559, 3], [2559, 2577, 3], [2577, 2637, 3], [2637, 2694, 3], [2694, 2716, 3], [2716, 2737, 2], [2737, 2764, 0], [2764, 2777, 0], [2777, 2779, 0], [2779, 2779, 0]]
```

I can not figure out how to do it - can this be done via looping through - any hint is much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really that hard.  Just write out the steps you would take if you were a human computer, and teach Python how to do it:

```
for l in list1:
    for m in list2:
        if m[0] <= l[1] <= m[1]:
            l.append(m[2])
            break
```

Comment: thank you for your answer - this looks really good. One more questions if I may: if list1 =[[0,0]] and list2=[], how could I deal with that? I tried adding try/exception, but I may add to skip, if l2 is empty, right?

Comment: What do you want the answer to be?  That wasn't part of the spec.  This code would not throw an exception, but it also won't change the original list.